# XML validation: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a error for PHMR 1.1

Tags: xml, validation, cda

I am trying to validate an XML using 
http://cda-validation.nist.gov/cda-validation/validation.html

**I need to validate it for PHMR v1.1**

The code is located at http://www.filedropper.com/cda4 , sorry but I couldn't find a better alternative to post a large code file.
Unfortunately I'm getting errors such as

```
Message cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'id'. One of '{"urn:hl7-org:v3":realmCode, "urn:hl7-org:v3":typeId}' is expected.

Message cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'parentDocument'. One of '{"urn:hl7-org:v3":realmCode, "urn:hl7-org:v3":typeId, "urn:hl7-org:v3":templateId, "urn:hl7-org:v3":patientRole}' is expected.

Message cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'currentEncounter'. One of '{"urn:hl7-org:v3":realmCode, "urn:hl7-org:v3":typeId, "urn:hl7-org:v3":templateId, "urn:hl7-org:v3":encompassingEncounter}' is expected.
```

I tried adding one of the suggestions from the error codes but that didn't help.
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add this below the root element:

```
<typeId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3" extension="POCD_HD000040"/>
```

Replace currentEncounter by encompassingEncounter.

To indicate related document you have inserted recordTarget instead of releatedDocuemnt.

Also header elements like author or custodian are not in the right order.

An advise to easy validations is taht you use some XML editor (like notepad++ plus xml plug-in or Oxygen) and validate against official schema.

Cheers.